# unable to set contextRoot in gradle ear

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using gradle ear plugin to generate ear file, but how can I set the contextroot? currently the default value is project name.
My project name is gradle-demo, here is my gradle file:

[image]
Here is the generate application.xml file, the context-root is gradle-demo, how to change it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, creating one application.xml file following this structure, and setting context-root in this file:
[image]